# how to add icon to chart in flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to create a crash game like this video:

[image: gif]

So I use [syncfusion_flutter_charts](https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts) to add charts to my app as this way:

```
SfCartesianChart(
      primaryXAxis: NumericAxis(),
      primaryYAxis: NumericAxis(),
      title: ChartTitle(text: chartData.length.toString()),
      legend: Legend(isVisible: false),
      series: <LineSeries<ChartSampleData, num>>[
        LineSeries<ChartSampleData, num>(
            dataSource: controller.chartData,
            xValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) =>
            data.x / 100,
            yValueMapper: (ChartSampleData data, _) =>
            data.y / 100,
            dataLabelSettings:
            DataLabelSettings(isVisible: true)),
      ],
    )
```

And use this code to generate data:

```
while (isStop == false) {
  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));
  this.x.value = this.x.value + 1;
  y.value = x.value * x.value;
  chartData.add(ChartSampleData(x: this.x.value, y: this.y.value));
}
```

My output of codes is this:

[image: output gif]

My question is how to add that spaceship to the end of the chart? Or can you have a better way to create that crash chart?

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about positionning:

To add the spaceship, you can add your chart in a `Stack` widget, and add the spaceship as the second child of your `Stack`. You can eventually use the `Positioned` or `Align` widget too.

If your question is about creating the animation:

You'll have to create the animation either directly with Flutter animations or with [Rive](https://rive.app/) or [Lottie](https://lottiefiles.com/). Both of them have dependencies that you can integrate on your project (you can find them on pub.dev) and you can create the animation directly on their website or through Adobe After Effect plug-ins.

Comment: I want to add a spaceShip icon, to the end of the chart that goes up with the chart. How to do that? how get the coordinates of the screen that the chart goes up?